# Why I am not able be see any expect methods like .toBe () in Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Why I am not able to see any methods for expect in protractor?

For example when use expect in protractor like below

```
expect(true).toBe(true);
```

After the dot I don't find any method as shown above `toBe()`

```
C:\>npm -g list
C:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- protractor@4.0.3
| +-- adm-zip@0.4.7
| +-- chalk@1.1.3
| | +-- ansi-styles@2.2.1
| | +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
| | +-- has-ansi@2.0.0
| | | `-- ansi-regex@2.0.0
| | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
| | `-- supports-color@2.0.0
| +-- glob@7.0.5
| | +-- fs.realpath@1.0.0
| | +-- inflight@1.0.5
| | | `-- wrappy@1.0.2
| | +-- inherits@2.0.1
| | +-- minimatch@3.0.3
| | | `-- brace-expansion@1.1.6
| | |   +-- balanced-match@0.4.2
| | |   `-- concat-map@0.0.1
| | +-- once@1.3.3
| | `-- path-is-absolute@1.0.0
| +-- jasmine@2.4.1
| | +-- exit@0.1.2
| | +-- glob@3.2.11
| | | `-- minimatch@0.3.0
| | |   +-- lru-cache@2.7.3
| | |   `-- sigmund@1.0.1
| | `-- jasmine-core@2.4.1
| +-- jasminewd2@0.0.9
| +-- optimist@0.6.1
| | +-- minimist@0.0.10
| | `-- wordwrap@0.0.3
| +-- protractor-html-screenshot-reporter@0.0.21 extraneous
| +-- protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter@0.0.6 extraneous
| +-- protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter@0.2.0 extraneous
| +-- q@1.4.1
```

Please also tell me if their is any direct command to find the Jasmine version just like `protractor --version`.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In order to see jasmine related functions you should have Jasmine type definitions. Do it as follows... first install typings globally as

```
npm install typings --global
```

now install jasmine type definitions

```
tsd install jasmine
```

Next put a reference of type definition file in your typescript test file in below manner.

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/main/ambient/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts" />
```

(note, path may be different based on where it is installed, correct it accordingly)

After this, you should be able to use all Jasmine matchers.

Regarding Jasmine version - 
I can see in your package.json it say Jasmine 2.4.1. So, 2.4.1 is the version. If you want to confirm it then use following command

```
npm view jasmine version
```

Comment: tsd install jasmine

Comment: 'tsd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: sure, I assumed that you have tsd installed. try "npm install -g tsd". This will install tsd globally and then you can try tsd install jasmine.

Comment: Thanks  for the quick help now this second command  "tsd install jasmine "got installed.

Comment: now i have another issue when i try this command "  tsd install jasmine"

Comment: below is error that i got when i tried " tsd install jasmine "

Comment: C:\>tsd install jasmine

Comment: [ERR!] cwd  : C:\[ERR!] cwd  : C:\
[ERR!] os   : Windows_NT 6.1.7601
[ERR!] argv : "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\x216526\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\tsd\\build\\cli.js" "install" "jasmine"
[ERR!] os   : Windows_NT 6.1.7601
[ERR!] argv : "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\x216526\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\tsd\\build\\cli.js" "install" "jasmine"

Comment: ERR!] node : v5.6.0
[ERR!] tsd  : 0.6.5
[ERR!] Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
[ERR!] CODE : UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
[ERR!] unable to get local issuer certificate
[ERR!] If you need help, you may report this error at:
    https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues

[ERR!] tsd.json could not be retrieved

[ERR!] .tsdrc could not be retrieved

Comment: I hope its something related to certificate issue because i am working on a secured VM with restricted rights.

Comment: you can do it in two way.. 1st and better way, create a tsdrc file and provide your proxy and other settings there.. https://github.com/Definitelytyped/tsd#tsdrc         the other way, just copy the jasmine.d.ts file from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts      (either download or copy content and paste in a file which is named jasmine.d.ts).. when you follow this second approach, you don't need tsd, so you can skip tsd related steps, do refer that new file as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

@Balaji, If I understood the question correctly you want to see the expect methods like `toBe` inside protractor? you can check it inside your global protractor folder, in your case open `C:\Users\x216526\AppData\Roaming\npm/protractor4.0.3`

- You can check the Jasmine version in package.json -

[image: Jasmin version]

- You can find the jasmine matchers i.e expect methods `toBe` inside the **node_modules** in jasmine core like this-

[image: matchers]

Comment: I doubt if he wants that, As the question mentions, when he types dot, after that, methods (matchers) like toBe() are not appearing as part of intellisense.

Comment: Thanks for all who pitched in . I understand this pacakge.json and Jasmine.js which contains all these  matchers. But i dont know why iam not able to see any matchers like "toBE " after dot. I dont see that various  listing matchers