# How to write Protractor test scripts using Typescript along with Jasmine framework in Visual studio Code?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, protractor, visual-studio-code

[image: Cannot find name Describe]My project is going from standalone to Web, Our new WebSite is getting created in AngularJS so Protractor is the tool selected for Test Automation.

I want to Integrate Typescript with dependencies of Jasmine and Node so that I don't get errors such as

```
cannot find name Describe
cannot find name it
cannot find name Expect
```

Can Anyone tell me how to add Jasmine and Protractor dependencies, so that when I hit ctrl + space i'll get all options available.

I have installed Typescript. And I am getting protractor dependencies such as browser, element, by etc.

What should i do for describe,it,expect (Jasmine stuffs) ?

Comment: check my answer in this question.. it is not exactly the same but I believe you have the same issue. You need type definition files for jasmine..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058504/why-i-am-not-able-be-see-any-expect-methods-like-tobe-in-protractor/39058896#39058896

Comment: Where can i find jasmine.d.ts file ?  I got the same error which balaji got.

Comment: /typings/main/ambient/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts there is no path like this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284366/how-to-integrate-protractor-test-cases-with-hiptest

Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use **Visual Studio Code** everyday to write my scripts, it's my current favourite editor for Protractor because of its built in support for TypeScript!

Here are the following things which can come into my mind which could help you setup your framework-

- Download the latest VS Code version - https://code.visualstudio.com/download
- Install typescript globally `npm install -g typescript`
- Install protractor globally `npm install -g protractor`
- Create your project folder
- Setup you project folder for git, node and typescript -

  ```
  npm init -f // will create default package.json stating its nodejs project
  git init  // will create .git file, you project is now git project
  tsc --init  // will create tsconfig.json stating its typescript project
  ```
- Install typings and dev dependencies-

  ```
  npm install --save-dev protractor // this will install protractor as a dev dependency
  npm install --save-dev typescript // this will install typescript as a dev dependency
  npm install --save-dev @types/jasmine // jasmine typings
  npm install --save-dev @types/node    // node typings
  ```
- At this point you have setup your basic `protractor-typescript` project and you can see all the typings and dependencies in `package.json`. Now you are good to write your typed scripts :).
- Now compile your scripts by running -

  ```
  tsc or tsc -w
  ```
- After successfull compilation all your javascript files would be generated.
- The run protractor

  ```
  protractor config.js
  ```
- You can also setup your vs code for debugging with protractor which I have mentioned here - [Protractor -VS Code Debugging](http://www.protractortest.org/#/debugging#setting-up-vscode-for-debugging)

For more details pls refer the [TypeScript Tutorial](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html), [Protractor API](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api)

The Typescript error you are observing this is due to VS Code not recognizing global typescript 2.0 version.

To solve this open vscode go to preferences--> user settings --> settings.json will be opened and enter the highlighted path as shown

[image]
Save your file and restart VSCode now you are good to go :)

Comment: I did all the steps suggested by you Ram. I created my first file as test.ts.
It still says cannot find name 'describe' and cannot find 'it'.

I added the screenshot. Please see.

Comment: import {$} from 'D:/nsWeb/node_modules/protractor/globals';


Is this the option?

Comment: no need to give the absolute path you can just give `import {$} from 'protractor/globals'` and the typescript error you are seeing that is an existing issue , they are working on it you would see it would show like that but it actually compiles successfully, this would be fixed in coming release!

Comment: My describe error is also gone now... Yupieeee. Thanks a ton Ram. Really I appreciate your efforts right from scratch.. I will always contact you for help. Can I ?

Comment: I have updated my answer as well if you face this issue in future you can look at it , you can change settings.json in vscode ! sure i would be happy to help

Comment: Yes Sure . Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more question.. How to make background white?

Comment: browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(module),
                                      8000).thenCatch(function () {
                  assert.fail(' element is not click able');


how can i import this assert ? I am getting cannot find name 'assert'.

Comment: node_modules/protractor/built/index.d.ts(1,1): error TS2654: Exported external package typings file cannot contain triple slash references. Please contact the package author to update the package defin ition.

Ram how to solve this?

Comment: You have to use typescript 2.0 and above versions `npm install -g typescript2.0`

Comment: typescript 2.0 is not in the npm registry

Comment: My protractor folder is not having globals.js. Why so ? Any Idea? @Ram Pasala

Comment: Globals have been removed from version 4.0.9!

Comment: So How can i include them ? import {$} from globals ?  Any Idea ?

Comment: Now you can import directly-` import {$} from 'protractor' `

Comment: You always tell me to use {$} , but it never works for me.
I have to use {browser,element and so on} from protractor , then only it works. Why so Ram?

Comment: Ram Can you help me on this ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284366/how-to-integrate-protractor-test-cases-with-hiptest

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answers given. Just want to share a hack with you.

**You don't need to transpile your Typescript codes to JavaScript anymore.**

Create a `launch.js` file

```js
require('ts-node').register({
  compilerOptions: {
    module: 'commonjs'
  },
  disableWarnings: true,
  fast: true
});
exports.config = require('./config/protractor.conf.ts').config;
```

And kick start protractor execution like:

```
> protractor launch
```

You can save yourself from the headache of transpiling every time you make a change to typescript files.

Happy testng!