# How to integrate Protractor test cases with Hiptest?

Tags: angularjs, testing, automation, protractor

For a Website which is made using angular js , our organization used protractor as the tool to automate test cases.

Our organization has come up with a new tool named 'HipTest' to manage test cases automation.
How to integrate protractor test cases with HipTest. I went to following links but was unable to fetch some useful information.

https://docs.hiptest.net/automate-your-tests/

https://github.com/hiptest/hiptest-publisher

Can Anyone help me how to start ?

Comment: http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/pageobjects.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm one of the main contributor or hiptest-publisher, so I should be able to help you.

The quick way to start with hiptest-publisher is to download the bootstrap of the tests from Hiptest (under the automation tab, you will have a "Javascript/Protractor" link).

You will get a zip file with four files (you should add all of them to your version control system, alongside the code of the application you are testing):
 - one for the configuration of hiptest-publisher to use the command-line tool
 - one for all the tests (you can split them later on, using the --with-folders option in the config file)
 - one for the action words: that's the place where you will do the automation
 - one for storing the status of the action words you exported (which is used with hiptest-publisher to see which action words have been updated since the last update)

Once the action words are implemented, the test files generated can be integrated in your test suite like any other Protractor test.

On the Hiptest side itself, the only requirement you have is that your tests should only be written using action words only. From what I understand from your post, you do not work directly in Hiptest yourself and you only manage the automation part (or did I get that wrong ? )

For pushing the execution results back to Hiptest, the principle is pretty simple:
 - create a test run dedicated to the CI
 - run the command "hiptest-publisher --config-file  --test-run-id " before the tests (so only the tests inside the test run are executed, you do not want to run a test that someone is currently writing to be executed on fail of course)
 - run your tests
 - run the command "hiptest-publisher --config-file  --push " to push the results back to hiptest.

Note that those two commands (including the test run ID) can be found directly inside Hiptest, from the "Automate" button in the test run.

If you have an Hiptest account, you can contact us directly on the chat, that might be easier to help you through the process.
Ho and I have a recording of the last webinar I made about automation, I guess you could find some useful information there too :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer. Yes i have account there but it is of organization. How to do chat ?
And yes you are right I only manage the automation section.

Can we have a discussion or chat?
beacuase my main question is, i write my test cases for automation using protractor tool and jasmine framework. But how to write the same things with hiptest ? I downloaded the zip for protractor.

Comment: I follow Hiptest on Youtube as well and watch both the webinar related to automation but I'm sorry, i was confused, because i was more interested in seeing how you create action words, but that video didn't show those. Please help me. Because my organization has almost decided to use Hiptest and we need to start working on it as soon as possible.
Please Guide me Vincent in any way you can. I'm desperate to work on this and excited as well.

Comment: When you log in to Hiptest, you'll see a button on the bottom right of the application. Click on it and you'll have access to the chat with the team :) That will be the easiest way to guide you I think :)