# Selecting a certain dropdown element using xpath (or better alternative)

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

How would I select a certain element in this drop down list.

```
<li role="presentation" ng-repeat="match in $matches" ng-class="{active: $isActive($index)}" class="ng-scope active">
    <a style="cursor: default" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" ng-click="$select($index, $event)">
        <!-- ngIf: $isMultiple && $isActive($index) -->
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right" ng-if="$isMultiple &amp;&amp; $isActive($index)"></i>
        <!-- end ngIf: $isMultiple && $isActive($index) --> 
        <span ng-bind="match.label" class="ng-binding">Streamer</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I tried this

```
element(by.model('selectedAvailable')).click();
element(by.xpath('..//ul//li[1]')).click().
```

and this:

```
element(by.repeater('match in $matches').row(0)).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use `by.cssContainingText` :

```
element(by.cssContainingText('[ng-repeat="match in $matches"]', 'Streamer')).click();
```

Comment: Can you see this ? please help..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284366/how-to-integrate-protractor-test-cases-with-hiptest

Comment: Hey Florent, Any Ideas why Its not finding the element?                                                                                         Message:
    Failed: No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText("[ng-repeat="match in $matches"]", "Streamer")
  Stack:
    NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText("[ng-repeat="match in $matches"]", "Streamer")

Comment: The element is probably not yet created. Try with a waiter: `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(...)), 15000);`

Comment: By using the wait, that error went away so the element is created. The element is not getting 'Clicked'. It appears that its clicking on the drop down again and not the item in this list for example "Streamer".

Answer (score 1):

I would [`filter()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) it, assuming you know the "Streamer" label and want to select it:

```
var matches = element.all(by.repeater('match in $matches')); 
matches.filter(function (match) {
    return match.element(by.binding("match.label")).getText().then(function (text) {
        return text === "Streamer";
    });
}).first().click();
```

Or, in a similar fashion with [`evaluate()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate) instead of `getText()`:

```
var matches = element(by.repeater('match in $matches')); 
matches.filter(function (match) {
    return match.evaluate("match.label").then(function (label) {
        return label === "Streamer";
    });
}).first().click();
```

Comment: I think you meant to write `element.all(by.repeater('match in $matches'))`.

Comment: alecxe .. Can you have a look at my question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284366/how-to-integrate-protractor-test-cases-with-hiptest